How much memory should I allocate to FastQC for analyzing large nanopore sequencing files?
I'm running a bioinformatics pipeline to analyze large nanopore sequencing files using FastQC. However, I keep running into an OutOfMemoryError. Here's what happens:
Unknown option: memory
Started analysis of SQK-NBD114-24_barcode16.fastq
Approx 5% complete for SQK-NBD114-24_barcode16.fastq
...
Approx 40% complete for SQK-NBD114-24_barcode16.fastq
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Utilities.QualityCount.<init>(QualityCount.java:33)
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Modules.PerBaseQualityScores.processSequence(PerBaseQualityScores.java:141)
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Analysis.AnalysisRunner.run(AnalysisRunner.java:89)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
^CError: FastQC failed for /home/jupyter/bioinfo_pipeline/demuxed_2/SQK-NBD114-24_barcode16.fastq. Exiting pipeline.

I attempted to allocate more memory by setting FASTQC_MEMORY="4g" and running FastQC with the following script:
# Allocate more memory to FastQC (e.g., 4GB)
FASTQC_MEMORY="4g"

# Loop over all .fastq files in the demuxed directory
for filename in "$DEMUX_DIR"/*.fastq; do
    echo -e "\nProcessing $filename..."
    
    #-= STEP 3 - SECOND quality control (FASTQC and NANOQC) =- 
    echo -e "\n~~~~~~-= Step 3, QC =-~~~~~~\n"
    OUTPUT_PC="$filename"  # Assuming OUTPUT_PC refers to the current .fastq file
    
    # Run FASTQC with increased memory allocation
    fastqc --outdir="$OUTPUT_QC" --memory="$FASTQC_MEMORY" "$OUTPUT_PC"
    
    # Check if FastQC failed due to memory issues or other errors
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: FastQC failed for $filename. Exiting pipeline."
        exit 1
    fi
done

But it seems like 4GB isn't enough, as the process still crashes. The file I'm working with is quite large (Nanopore sequencing data):
-rw-r--r-- 1 jupyter jupyter 442198080 Aug 27 14:49 SQK-NBD114-24_barcode16.fastq

According to free -h, I have 22 GiB of available memory. How much memory should I allocate to FastQC to prevent these errors? Is there a rule of thumb or specific calculation I should use when working with large .fastq files?

For now I would say give it like 15-20 GB and see if you run into the same error. Which version of FastQC are you using?

Where did you get this --memory option? That doesn't seem to exist. Note the first line of your error output: Unknown option: memory. On my fastqc version 0.12.1, the --memory option is known, but only takes values in megabytes. Check that your version i) has a --memory option and ii) it can accept the string 4g as a valid value.

@Karthik Nair FastQC v0.11.9

Using more threads solves the problem.
Run FASTQC with increased memory allocation
fastqc --outdir="$OUTPUT_QC" -t 10 "$OUTPUT_PC"

